# don't repaint or revalidate

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, repaint

When the program is running, the button is drawn 10X10. 
I changed the button 20X20 by Modify Menu.
However, the button is not visible.

Appears when you move the mouse over the button.
Do not be a repaint.
revalidate also not the same.

```
package com.test; 

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MenuTest extends JFrame {

    private Dimension dimen, dimen1;
    private int xpos, ypos;
    private JButton[][] btn = null;
    private JPanel p;
    private GridLayout grid;
    private CardLayout card;
    private int rownum;
    private int colnum;
    private int mineLevel;

    public MenuTest() {
        super("GAME");

        p = new JPanel();
        grid = new GridLayout();
        card = new CardLayout();

        createMenu();
        starting();
    }

    private void createMenu() {
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(bar);

        JMenu filemenu = new JMenu("파일(F)");
        filemenu.setMnemonic('F');

        JMenuItem startmenu = new JMenuItem("게임 시작(S)");
        startmenu.setMnemonic('S');
        startmenu.setActionCommand("START");
        startmenu.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        filemenu.add(startmenu);

        JMenuItem minecntmenu = new JMenuItem("변경(M)");
        minecntmenu.setMnemonic('M');
        minecntmenu.setActionCommand("MODIFY");
        minecntmenu.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        filemenu.add(minecntmenu);

        JMenuItem close = new JMenuItem("닫기(C)");
        close.setMnemonic('C');
        filemenu.add(close);
        bar.add(filemenu); //JMenuBar에 JMenu 부착 

        //도움말 메뉴 만들기-------------------------------- 
        JMenu helpmenu = new JMenu("도움말(D)");
        helpmenu.setMnemonic('D'); //단축키를 Alf + D 로 설정 

        JMenuItem help = new JMenuItem("Help(H)");
        help.setMnemonic('H');
        helpmenu.add(help);
        bar.add(helpmenu);
    }

    private class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("START")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "게임시작", "게임", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("MODIFY")) {
                modify();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "변경", "게임", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            }
        }
    }

    private void modify() {
        btn = null;

        setRowColnum(20, 20);
        MapInit(20);
        LayoutSet(400, 500);
    }

    private void starting() {
        setRowColnum(10, 10);
        MapInit(10);
        LayoutSet(200, 250);
    }

    private void setRowColnum(int rownum, int colnum) {
        this.rownum = rownum;
        this.colnum = colnum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        MenuTest mt = new MenuTest();
    }

    public void LayoutSet(int w, int h) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(w, h);

        dimen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        dimen1 = this.getSize();
        xpos = (int) (dimen.getWidth() / 2 - dimen1.getWidth() / 2);
        ypos = (int) (dimen.getHeight() / 2 - dimen1.getHeight() / 2);
        this.setLocation(xpos, ypos);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
    }

    public void MapInit(int minecnt) {
        p.removeAll();
        setBtn(rownum, colnum);

        card = new CardLayout(5, 5);
        this.setLayout(card);
        grid = new GridLayout(rownum, colnum, 0, 0);

        p = new JPanel(grid);

        int action_num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < btn[i].length; j++) {
                action_num = (i * 10 + j);
                btn[i][j] = new JButton();
                p.add(btn[i][j]);
            }
        }

        this.repaint();

        this.add("View", p);
    }

    private void setBtn(int row, int col) {
        btn = new JButton[row][col];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add/remove components from a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
...
panel.revalidate();
panel.reapint();
```

After removing/adding all the components you need to do the `revalidate()` so the layout manager is invoked and all the components are given a size and location. Then the `repaint()` makes sure the components are painted.

Comment: Don't.... ㅠㅠ

public void MapInit(int minecnt){ 
1 -----> p.removeAll(); 
setBtn(rownum, colnum); 

card = new CardLayout(5, 5); 
this.setLayout(card); 
grid = new GridLayout(rownum, colnum, 0, 0); 

p = new JPanel(grid); 

int action_num = 0; 
for(int i=0;i<btn.length;i++){ 
for(int j=0;j<btn[i].length;j++){ 
action_num = (i*10+j); 
btn[i][j] = new JButton(); 
2 -----> p.add(btn[i][j]); 
3 -----> p.revalidate();
4 -----> p.repaint();
} 
}

Comment: When I did some animation loops recently, `revalidate()` was enough for me.  I was completely replacing a JLabel (with a custom image) inside a JFrame.

Comment: Not yet. 
Plz...Could you modify the source?